# Compilation Error in mvc 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

i am using mvc 4 application. actually my application it should running correctly by suddenly it showing compilation error and cleared all the temp files also it not working please help me

My error is:

[image]

View Code

```
    <div id="page-wrapper">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="@ViewBag.HideClass">
            @ViewBag.Message
        </div>
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <h2 class="page-header"> User Registration </h2>
                <input type="hidden" id="MenuId" value="@(int)MenuDetails.MenuCompanyMaster" />
            </div>
            <!-- /.col-lg-12 -->                            
    </div>
```

thank in advane

Comment: Please can you provide your code ?

Comment: which code you want its controller or model i cannot understand sorry

Comment: The view page (CSHTML).

Comment: Also, click "Show Complete Compilation Source" and share more of the preceding lines of code (e.g. lines 170 - 190).

Comment: Controllers code where this error is showing

Comment: Ya i update my question

Comment: why you need to parse int in hidden field ?? what ever the data is , it always will become string in input field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your view page try changing this:

```
value="@(int)MenuDetails.MenuCompanyMaster"
```

To this:

```
value="@((int)MenuDetails.MenuCompanyMaster)"
```

In Razor syntax, an `@` section followed by a `(` will end the C# code at the nearest matching `)`. In this case, it's just the `@(int)`. The `MenuDetails.MenuCompanyMaster` section ends up being random other markup. By wrapping everything in an extra `()` it indicates to the Razor parser that it's all one expression.

However, I'm not certain if that will fully solve the problem that you have.